# How to translate "grassland" with a focus on the land cover

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

Grassland in English include all types of land covered with grass. There are several words for this in French (pelouse, prairie, pré, herbage, gazon), but those terms are usually related with the land USE. I would like a single term that includes all the different land uses (natural grassland, pasture, garden...). Does such single word exist or should I use "formation herbeuse" or something similar.

Note : I am looking for this word in order to label a land cover on a map with herbaceous vegetation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about naming the label frame "Végétation" or "Couverture végétale" and use labels like "arbres", "herbes" etc.?

Comment: That's a good idea but not perfectly accurate: I was looking for an equivalent of "forêt" for "arbre"

Comment: I've tried to find a definition that is never ambiguous in the above examples, but the land use component is always present. Your suggestion is therefore the best but I'll need to renaim my other classes for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Dans les mots cités *pelouse, prairie, pré, herbage, gazon*, ***[herbage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/herbage)*** (herbe des prés) est le terme générique qui recouvre toutes les surfaces agricoles recouvertes d'herbes.

- *pelouse, gazon* : herbage privé ou citadin, peu utilisé pour définir un paysage.
- *prairie* : fourni des plantes herbacées destinées à l'élevage
- *pré, pâturage, embouche* : synonyme de prairie, on l'utilise aussi pour parquer les animaux
- *jachère* : zone ensemencée de plantes sélectionnées (pour favoriser la prolifération des insectes mellifères) ou laissée telle quelle afin de mettre les terres agricoles au repos, et éventuellement fournir du fourrage.
- *[alpage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpage)* : zone de montagne entretenue par les bovins ou les ovins lors des transhumances estivales.

Une *zone herbagère* est un endroit de la campagne où poussent des herbes de toutes natures, céréales et *zones maraîchères* exclues.

Comment: "zone herbagère" me semble approprié, mais en deux mots. Par contre, la définition Larousse d'herbage ne me convient pas :  "Herbage : Prairie servant de pâture au bétail"

Comment: en continuant mes vérifications, "zone herbagère" est finalement trop lié à la production d'herbe (prés + pâturages), n'incluant donc pas les pelouses naturelles ou les gazons.

Comment: @radouxju Il n'y a pas de pelouse naturelle ni de gazon naturel. L'alpage désigne un pâturage estival où les vaches et les moutons jouent le rôle de tondeuses à gazon, il peut donner aux citadins l'impression d'une pelouse naturelle, mais c'est un espace agricole entretenu par l'activité humaine. De même *l'herbage* est une prairie naturelle dont l'herbe, consommée sur place, est suffisamment riche pour l'engraissement (2ème def du Robert). Non entretenu, l'espace devient une friche envahie par les ronces et buissons où *l'herbe* disparait.

Comment: @radouxju Dans la réponse, j'ai mis le lien derrière la définition *d'herbage*, toutes vos définitions se rapportent aux *herbes* naturelles qui ont été sélectionnées par l'homme et sont entretenues mécaniquement ou par des animaux domestiqués.

Comment: Merci pour le complément d'information. Par pelouse naturelle j'entendais pelouse calcaire http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelouse_calcaire qui sont souvent d'origine agro-pastorale mais dont ce n'est pas la finalité (elles sont conservées pour leur grande biodiversité, pas dans le but d'élever du bétail, même certains gestionnaires utilisent du bétail pour les entretenir). Ce sont par ailleurs parfois des animaux sauvages (ex lapins) qui "entretiennent" ces pelouses, sans intervention de l'homme.

Comment: concernant les gazons, il y a effectivement action mécanique (terrain de sport, jardin...) mais, encore une fois, pas de "production" d'herbe (l'herbe est d'ailleurs souvent jetée). Je me demandais s'il existait un mot pour regrouper toutes ces catégories (prairies + pré de fauche + pelouse + gazon + alpage + ...)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for either *prairies* or *herbages* but in the **plural**.

**Herbages**  is the generic term for anything planted with grass that is either agricultural land planted with grass or just the produce of Mother Nature.
It is the term usually used in real estate for any sort of grassland, and it is used in more specific context too, as for instance in the curricular of this Swiss [School of Agricultural, Forest and Food Sciences](http://www.hafl.bfh.ch/fr/recherche-et-prestations/sciences-agronomiques/durabilite-et-ecosystemes/ecologie-des-herbages.html). You can compare their how they use the two words,  *grassland* and *herbages*, by checking their English text. I would trust this particular university in this specific field.

Comment: thank you for the link, however they seem to focus on grass production land use.

Answer (score 1):

Les légendes des cartes IGN n'ont aucun terme pour les couvertures herbeuses. Elles sont interprétées de la sorte par défaut. Si c'est vert mais que ce n'est ni un bois, ni des broussailles, ni d'autres plantations, alors c'est de l'herbe.

[image: Eléments de surface]

(image reprise de [La toile scoute](http://www.latoilescoute.net/legende-des-cartes-ign))

Comment: merci pour l'information. Dans mon cas j'aimerais toutefois nommer chaque classe car les zones couvertes d'herbe jouent un rôle très important. A noter que l'IGN belge (http://www.ngi.be/Common/leg10/10000FR.htm#top) a des classes pour les zones couvertes herbes (jardin, pelouse, prairie permanente ou pré de fauche), mais, encore une fois, c'est une description de l'utilisation du sol

Answer (score 1):

Après avoir fait le tour de toutes les suggestions, je pense que "zone enherbée" pourrait convenir pour décrire ce que je recherche : tout type de surface couverte par de l'herbe.

Rem : Si quelqu'un connaissait un exemple d'utilisation de ce terme qui le rendrait plus spécifique, merci de me le signaler.

Comment: je crois que les zones enherbées sont délimitées en superficie et entretenues, je ne crois pas qu'on puisse l'appliquer pour une surface zone où l'herbe pousse de façon sauvage. J'ai regardé ce que donnait « surface enherbée  » et ce n'est pas concluant non plus, [par exemple](http://www.coordinationrurale.fr/foot-et-agriculture-a-part-la-surface-enherbee-quel-point-commun.html). Mais je suis tombée sur « couvert herbacé » [dans ce document.](http://www.observatoire-marin.com/request.php?module=Content_OMDocumentsViewer&file=126), peut-être une piste ?

Answer (score 1):

Je n'ai pas de mot unique pour *grassland*, mais j'en ai trouvé un petit nombre qui met plus l'accent sur la nature du terrain que sur son usage (certains mots peuvent aussi désigner des couvertures autres qu'herbeuses ou incluant des broussailles):

- En Asie Centrale, on parle de steppe.
- En Afrique, on parle de savane, de brousse ou de veld.
- En Amérique du Sud, on parle de pampa.
- En Australie, on parle de bush.
- Dans les zones arctiques, on parle de toundra.
- Dans les Alpes, on parle d'alpage; dans les Pyrénées, on parle d'estive.
- En Europe, on parle de lande, de garrigue ou de causse.

Pour plus d'exhaustivité et de généralisation, on peut consulter Wikipédia: [Liste des formations végétales](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_formations_v%C3%A9g%C3%A9tales).

Comment: Merci, mais la plupart des termes mentionnés comprennent généralement de la végétation ligneuse (bush, brousse, garrigue, lande (selon le type), savane (selon le type), veld). Par ailleurs, ces formations ont une spécificité géographique que je voudrais éviter (ma carte couvre toute l'Europe).